# Trained U-Net shall predict CT images based on parameters/weights after 60 epochs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, prediction

my U-Net shall predict CT images from MRIs. I have already trained and validated the U-Net with  concatenated 3D MRIs/CTs as follows:

```
def train_valid_model(X, Y, x_val, y_val):

    s = X.shape
    model = UNet_model_2D(s[1], s[2], 1)  # s[1]=256, s[2]=256 
    
    callbacks = [
        tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(
            log_dir='logs',
            histogram_freq=1,
            write_graph=True,
            write_images=True,
        )
    ]
    
    # return a History object whose attribute '.history ' is a record of  
    # training loss, metrics, validation loss, and validation metrics values
    results = model.fit(
        x=X,  # concatenated 3D MRIs
        y=Y,  # concatenated 3D reference CTs
        batch_size=16, 
        epochs=200,
        verbose=1,
        callbacks=callbacks,
        validation_data = (x_val, y_val),  # concatenated 3D MRIs/CTs
    )
    
    tmp = list(results.history.values())
    
    train_loss=tmp[0][:]  # train loss
    val_loss=tmp[1][:]  # val loss
    
    # write/append csv file
    f = open('log_train_loss_TF_CT.csv', 'a')
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(train_loss)
    f.close()
    f = open('log_val_loss_TF_CT.csv', 'a')
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(val_loss)
    f.close()
    
    model.save('pCT_2D_deep_large_batch16', save_format='tf')
```

Looking at the loss function graph in TensorBoard, I found that after 60 epochs, there is a good compromise between further convergence and overfitting. Therefore, I now want to predict the CTs from the concatenated test MRIs with the model parameters/weights as they were after 60 epochs. How do I do this?

I have the following approach so far:

```
# load trained & validated model
model_name = 'pCT_2D_deep_large_batch16'
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_name, compile=False)

# load concatenated test MRIs
X_test = nib.load('test_MRIs.nii.gz').get_fdata()

# predict sCTs
predicted_data = model.predict(X_test, verbose=1)

# save predicted sCTs as concatenated NIfTI file
image = nib.Nifti1Image(predicted_data, affine=None)
nib.save(image, 'predicted_sCTs.nii.gz')
```

In the Spyder console, this is what comes up:
[image]

Is there any way to stop at 60/200? Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What does your attempt do?

Comment: It predicts concatenated 3D pseudoCTs from concatenated 3D test MRIs and saves the result as NIfTI file.

Comment: I don't mean "what do you want it to do", I mean "what happens when you try to run your code"?

Comment: It predicts the concatenated pseudoCTs from the fed test MRIs, but probably based on the model after 200 epochs.

Answer (score 1):

If the only model saved is after 200 epochs, there is no straightforward way to retrieve the weights at 60 epochs.

If retraining is possible, the easiest solution would be to retrain but use `model.fit(..., epochs=60, ...)` and see that the loss goes roughly where it was in the previous training.

Additionally, Keras' [ModelCheckpoint](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/model_checkpoint/) callback can be useful for saving checkpoints during training so that the intermediate model weights are not lost.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, re-training is an option. Training/validation took less than 1 day. Alright, then I'll train the U-Net again, but this time with the ModelCheckpoint.